# Equations that make no sense (explaining the vector bundle isomorphism)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I'm stuck at two places in [these](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~mike/teaching/ss08/dg.pdf) lecture notes:

**1) Consider on pp 40:**

[image]
What does the last equation mean? This makes no sense to me. $\varphi_i$, $i=1,2$ can't denote the $i$th coordinate function, since that takes 2 arguments, not one. What does it the denote? And what is the $\cdot$? The scalar product?!

**2) Consider on pp. 53**

[image]

[image]

($T^r_s(E)$ are the $\binom{r}{s}$-tensors on the vector space $E$, as defined previously in the notes - see the link.)
I cannot understand the equation $e(\varphi^* (\beta)) = \varphi (e) (\beta)$, or why $\varphi_0^1$ is in some sense isomorphic to $\varphi$.

Here $\varphi: E \rightarrow F$ for finite-dim. real vector spaces $E,F$ and $\varphi^*$ is the adjoint, $e \in E^{**}$ and $\beta \in F^*$ (this is all explained in the lines above this example).

Actually the equation makes no sense in my opinion, since $\varphi(e)$ is an element of $F$, so it makes no sense to apply $\beta$ here.

Comment: In definition 2.5.5., what comes after the trailing comma?  Also, there is nothing wrong with writing something like $\phi(u,f) = \phi_1(u)$.  The notation $\phi(u,f)$ is not a promise that $\phi$ actually depends on both $u$ and $f$, it just allows for that possibility.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Well, you can look it up, that's why I linked the source. Quoting from there: "where
φ
2
(
u
)
is linear (resp. a linear isomorphism) from
F
to (resp. onto)
F
′
for each
u
∈
U
." Maybe I should have added that ... but I'm still confused, of $\varphi_i$ are specific functions or not. would it have been correct to say "$\varphi$ is a *local vector bundle homo/isomorphism if <blablabla> and there exist maps $\alpha:U\rightarrow F$ and $\beta: U \rightarrow \text{Hom}(F,F')$ s.t. $\varphi(u,f)=(\alpha(u),\beta(u)(f))$"*?

Comment: @JasonDeVito But there is something wrong with the equation as he writes it, if $\varphi$ are the coordoniate function, since neither depend on $f$, so then also $\varphi$ should not depend on $f$, yet it does.

Comment: Sorry about missing the link you posted.  In fact, $\phi$ does depend on $f$, in the second coordinate.  $\phi_2(u)$ does not depend on $f$, but, as PtF points out below, $\phi_2(u)$ is itself a linear transformation which then acts on $f$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Coming back to my italic question above, are the $\varphi_{1,2}$ thus any function that I can preassign?

Comment: Sort of.  In order to just have a local vector bundle homomorphism, yes, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ can be any preassigned (smooth?) functions.  However, when you consider *global* vector bundles (which are locally given by local vector bundles), you impose a compatibility condition between a choice $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ in one open set and another choice $(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ on an overlapping open set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to your first question, the map $\varphi$ has two components $$(u, f)\longmapsto \varphi_1(u)\quad \textrm{and}\quad (u, f)\longmapsto \varphi_2(u)\cdot f,$$

where $\varphi_1:U\longrightarrow F$ and $\varphi_2:U\longrightarrow \mathsf{Hom}(F, F^\prime)$ where $\mathsf{Hom}(F, F^\prime)$ is the vector space of linear maps from $F$ to $F^\prime$. This applies to the definition of local vector bundle homomorphism.

If you change "homomorphism" by "isomorphism" you must change $\mathsf{Hom}(F, F^\prime)$ by $\mathsf{Iso}(F, F^\prime)$ where $\mathsf{Iso}(F, F^\prime)$ is the vector space of linear isomorphism from $F$ to $F^\prime$.

As to your second question, when he writes $\varphi_2(u)\cdot f$ it means you are evaluating the linear map $\varphi_2(u):F\longrightarrow F^\prime$ in the point $f\in F$.

As to your last question, I believe he is defining $\varphi_0^1:E\longrightarrow F$ via duality. There are natural pairings $$\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle_E:E\times E^*\longrightarrow \mathbb R$$ and $$\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_F: F\times F^*\longrightarrow \mathbb R$$ and he defines $\varphi_0^1:E\longrightarrow F$ as the unique map such that $$\langle \varphi_0^1(e), \beta\rangle_F=\langle e, \varphi^*(\beta)\rangle_E=\langle \varphi(e), \beta\rangle$$ for every $e\in E$ and $\beta\in F^*$.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. I would not have been able to come up with what that!! For the first question, just a clarification: So the $\varphi_1, \varphi_2$ are *any* maps (with domain and image as you specified)? Because given their name, I thought one would have defined them by using $\varphi$ somehow. Thus would it have been correct to say "$\varphi$ is a *local vector bundle homo/isomorphism if <blablabla> and there exist maps $\alpha:U\rightarrow F$ and $\beta: U \rightarrow \text{Hom}(F,F')$ s.t. $\varphi(u,f)=(\alpha(u),\beta(u)(f))$"*?

Comment: I think I mislead you for my last question, I apologize. I was hoping that in case there were unclear issues you'd look up since link I provided, since I didn't want to copy too much from there to make my question long. I edited in now and added stuff: The $ \varphi_0^1$ is explicitly defined, so there is no need to use pairing (does his definition actually generalize what you wrote? I'm not sure...), so $\varphi_0^1 (e)(\beta)=e(\varphi^*(\beta))$ is clear - but I don't understand the next equation.